# Pickery on click work`s only one time

Tags: jquery

I`m using`pickery`library and I have a problem trigger`pickery` on second click function

```
$(document).on('click', 'menu li', function(){
    check_content();
});
function check_content(type){
    content.html('');
    content.imagesLoaded()
    .done(function(instance){
        content.fadeIn(500, function(){
            content.packery({itemSelector: '.photo', gutter: 10});
            loader.fadeOut(500);
        });

    });
};
```

Comment: what problem? show also html if it's relevant

Comment: in this case i think it's not relevant. First time I click on menu, its load content and pickery works fine, but when i click on another menu its load content, but pickery won`t work.

Comment: What is the `content` variable role?

Comment: var content = $('.content');

Comment: content variable is where is loading content in this case multiple .photo